# How to draw the area around a shape

Tags: java, geometry, awt

I worked on a very simple map editor phase for a game in java. The goal is to put some islands with different shape on the map. But there is some constraints:

- islands must not be a specific distance far from another island (lets call it L)
- islands must not be a specific distance close from another island (lets call it S)

In the game, the island is place with the mouse. The gamer can see areas where the island can be place or not as you can see.

[image: Allowed and dissallowed areas]

My problem is that I realize my disalow area is not good. For example, the rectangle island have a rectangle disallow area (my first naive attempt) but in fact I must draw area of S around the rectangle ; that leads to a shape like this:

[image: rectangle with real disallow area]

I'm able to draw these kind of areas as long as my shapes are just composed of lines. But my island can have cubic or quadratic curve (and even though i'll need this kind of area for other shapes later).
The closer I manage to do is that:

[image: disallow area for a circle]

In this case, the disallow area around the circle must be ... a circle (simple geometry). But as you can see, I have a weird rounded rectangle.

I currently try to transform each segment of the pathiterator of a Shape to get the area. It's not as simple as scaling a shape (remember the rectangle case). I've allready try many ways to transform the shape and get the area.

**Question:**

Does someone have information, formula, clues, algorithms, libs to get this area from any java.awt.Shape (or PathIterator) and a distance?

Comment: What you are trying to get is called [offset or buffer of the curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve). Clipper2 is a good library that does that. It also has a java port: https://github.com/micycle1/Clipper2-java/

Comment: Ok. I taked the time to read about Clipper2 for java. I understand the mecanism, but it doesn't fit to my usage. My starting shape are `java.awt.Shape` or its `PathIterator`.
But this lib can be usefull. Event though you've put words on what I looking for!

Comment: I find this: [Expand shape in all direction by a defined offset](http://www.java2s.com/example/java/java.lang/expand-or-shrink-a-shape-in-all-directions-by-a-defined-offset.html) It's minimalist, maybe not very accurate but it's very simple and fit to my usage. Waiting for other proposals.

Comment: I've got an emotional rollercoaster... It works with circle ... but not with rectangle :D I keep looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.java2s.com/example/java/java.lang/expand-or-shrink-a-shape-in-all-directions-by-a-defined-offset.html

This site describe how to use stroke to get the offset area.

There is just a single modification to solve my problem ; I have to use `BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND` to get the good rectangular Shape.

Then I get:

[image]

[image]

[image]